# String replace (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of string:

```
'Dow<br> <span class="table-sub-header">Value</span>'
```

I want to replace 'Value' inside the span with an arbitrary variable. I know that the span class will be there every time.

I've tried things like:

```
var s = 'Dow<br> <span class="table-sub-header">Value</span>';
```

And then doing a replace with something like this as the regex:

```
/<span class="table-sub-header">*</span>/
```

But it looks messy. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Edit: 'Value' in this case is arbitrary. I don't know what it is and I wanted a general method to replace what is in the span.

Comment: Are you within a browser environment?  Can you interact with the DOM to get hold of this?

Comment: I am on the browser and I'm getting this value as a property from a library object. I thought it would be weird to change it to a DOM object just for a string placement, especially since I would need to convert the DOM object back to a string.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working in browser, you may try put `s` in some element `innerHTML` and replace it as it in dom do

```
var s = 'Dow<br> <span class="table-sub-header">Value</span>';
t = document.createElement('div');
t.innerHTML = s;
t.querySelector('.table-sub-header').textContent = 'Something Else';
t.innerHTML // 'Dow<br> <span class="table-sub-header">Something Else</span>'
```

BTW, your regexp should be something like `/<span class="table-sub-header">(.*)<\/span>/`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `replace` string method?

```
var s = 'Dow<br> <span class="table-sub-header">Value</span>';
s = s.replace("Value", "New Value");
```

Comment: While that answers the very specific example in the question, I'm not sure that's what the OP is after.  If you're doing that, you may as well just write `var s = 'Dow<br> <span class="table-sub-header">New Value</span>';` in the first place.

Comment: If he's working with strings, then this is the simplest. If he's working with HTML elements (and not strings), then either @tsh answer or `$(".table-sub-header").text("my text")`

Comment: But he mentioned string...hence the answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use jQuery for this.

```js
var s = 'Dow<br> <span class="table-sub-header">Value</span>';

var div_wrapper = '<div style="display:none;">'+s+'</div>';

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append(div_wrapper);
    var new_value = 'newvalue'; // an arbitrary variable
     $('.table-sub-header').text(new_value);
     console.log($('.table-sub-header').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <body>
    
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: is string `s` trustable? what if `s = 'Dow<br> <span class="table-sub-header"><script>alert(/xss/)</script></span>'`

Comment: @tsh string s should be trustable, Else you need to refine it before appending it to div using javascripts filter html tags option.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically replace what is in the `span` tag by using JavaScript or any JavaScript library. For example using Javascript you can use a class selector to select the span and set the inner html to whatever value you want based on a condition or logic of some sort. You can also use Jquery `.text()`

refer to the links below
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
http://api.jquery.com/text/